# Under which site should questions about research methods go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was asking a [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/99496/are-meta-analyses-a-scientifically-robust-form-of-investigation) about the scientific utility of meta-analyses and the question was put on hold as being off topic.

> I came across a very interesting view recently. In a scientific
>   debate,  I decided to utilize the results of a meta-analysis. The
>   opponent quickly rejected the meta-analysis and pointed out that he
>   does not trust them. Or as he put it, he sees "metas as only
>   incrementally better than placing the entrails of a goat on one's
>   keyboard."
>
> This first off, spurred me to write a [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/99496/are-meta-analyses-a-scientifically-robust-form-of-investigation) specifically on
>   the quality of the meta-analysis that I cited. But I figured now I
>   should ask a broader question. Are meta-analyses in general, useful
>   and reliable? I will provide my own answer to start.

I think academia is a good place to ask about research methods, and the only other site I could think of would be philosophy, which could be seen as a catch all.

Where should such a question go?

Comment: Such a question is *highly* opinion based, so even if there were a site where questions about research methods would be on topic, that question wouldn't be.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable philosophy of science question: "is method x a valid scientific method?"

Comment: No, that's just asking for people's opinions.  You would need to define a specific and objectively evaluable metric of the analysis method to ask your question about.  For example, you could ask about rates of overturned results of various methods, how often a study using a given method is published, or other such metrics that are facts, and not opinions.

Comment: So if I asked "is creationism a valid scientific theory" I would have to provide the potential metrics by which that would be judged? If I had those metrics, why would I even need to ask the question?

Comment: If you don't even know by what means you'd evaluate the validity of something, why *would* you ask the question?  Knowing by what metrics you'd measure the validity of something doesn't mean that you know the answer to the question.  You could be asking if there's consensus (which you'd need to further define by perhaps asking about what percentage of experts in the field support it, or what percentage of recently published papers support it), you could be asking if there's been published evidence meeting some given criteria supporting (or disproving) the theory published, etc.

Comment: Just asking about whether something is "valid" given no context or definition, simply isn't answerable, and is likely to result in opinions, not facts.

Comment: If I knew the means to evaluate something, why would I ask a question at all? Why would I ask "is x a valid scientific theory" if I had the metric needed to determine if it was?

Comment: @Servy, I specifically asked if it was a robust scientific method.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you need to ask it?  How is knowing the metrics by which you determine the correctness of an answer going to result in you not needing to ask the question?

Comment: So what does "robust scientific method" mean?  How do you demonstrate, objectively, whether something is a robust scientific method or not?  By what criteria do you determine if a method is robust?

Comment: Is 2 greater than 3? Why ask that question if you know the metric to determine which is greater? In any case, this is getting into an extended discussion and really is not getting us anywhere.

Comment: In that case you're using a term that has an unambiguous, well defined, meaning.  3 is *defined* as being greater than 2, given the numeric systems you're using, and simply isn't a good analogy for your question, as there is no well defined, unambiguous, definition for "valid" in the context of your question.  A much better analogy would be if someone were to ask, "Is it hot outside?", which doesn't have a well defined metric to determine the validity of an answer, unlike "Is it hotter than 85F outside?" which has a well defined metric, and may still need to be asked.

Comment: 3 is not defined as being greater than 2. I suggest you actually take a course in number theory.

Comment: It's defined as following it, and the "greater than" operator is defined as being true if the second operator follows that number in the sequence.  But anyway, the specifics of a proper proof aside, there *is* a well defined definition for "greater than" that has an unambiguous meaning in that context, so the answer is a fact, not a matter of opinion.  That's not true of a statement like, "Are meta analysis useful?" which is a matter of *opinion*, not fact.  The point remains that the question needs an objective metric for evaluating the answer, and having one doesn't mean you know the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1160/discussion-between-daniel-goldman-and-servy).